# Adding scrollbar to console

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-console

How to add scroll bar to console using `system` function?

I'm using `system("MODE 100,50");` to set customize console window size.

Comment: Why not to use Win32 API?

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked. `System` is much simpler...

Answer (score 2):

What can be simplier?

```
COORD newSize = {100,9999};
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), newSize);
```

newSize must be larger than your current visible window area

Comment: It works but 9999 is just too big. I was hoping I could fixed it 50 and and use scroll bar. Is there anyway to make the console window don't larger than my desktop monitor to make the scroll bar works?

Comment: What are you talking about? You may set **any** height of buffer. Of course, buffer **must** be larger than you current visible window area, otherwise there will be no scrollbars.

Comment: Maybe drop a 9 to keep the OP happy?